# How to get the database view in MOTOR Tornado?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, tornado-motor

I have a database .
In that I want to view all the entries that have been inserted. 
For that I made a route '/db' and added the below RequestHandler to it.

```
class dbHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        db = self.settings['db']
        result = yield db.ip.find()
        for res in result:
           self.write(res)
```

This gives me Error 505 when I open /db route. 
How to get the data of ip?

Comment: Show stacktrace of an error. Also it would help if you write (or enclose code) what is in settings['db']

Comment: It shows : yielded unknown object MotorCursor(<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0xb695cb4c>)
In settings['db'] contains the database settings. That's it. above it, db contains the database .

Answer (score 1):

Motor's `find` returns only the cursor, it is not `Future` - it cannot be yielded. You can iterate over it with [`fetch_next`](https://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_cursor.html?highlight=fetch_next#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCursor.fetch_next), or use [`to_list`](https://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_cursor.html?highlight=fetch_next#motor.motor_tornado.MotorCursor.to_list) to fetch more data (or more info in [docs](https://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/motor_cursor.html)). Some sort of example

```
@gen.coroutine
def get(self):
    db = self.settings['db']
    cursor = db.ip.find()
    res = yield cursor.to_list(length=100)
    self.write(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Motor is asynchronous. In order to get the result of a database operation like `find`, you must `yield` the Future it returns to resolve the Future into a result:

```
cursor = db.test_collection.find({'i': {'$lt': 5}}).sort('i')
for document in (yield cursor.to_list(length=100)):
    self.write(str(document))
```

For more info, see the tutorial:

http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial-tornado.html#querying-for-more-than-one-document